# How to integrate the Springboot with Katonic AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am trying to learn the Katonic AI open source platform. We can train the AI according to our purpose.

I am trying to develop the Finance related project for that i need an AI Integration but i don't know how to integrate Katonic AI  in my spring boot(v 2.17.7) project.